# MongoDB: Migrate some YYYY-MM-DD dates to ISO 8601

Tags: mongodb

I have a field with dates stored in different formats (due to a code change at some point):

Some documents in the same collection use ISO 8601 ("2022-06-27T00:00:00.000Z"), while some others use the YYYY-MM-DD syntax ("2022-06-27").

This is a problem, because this query fails to fetch the YYYY-MM-DD documents (while it does fetch the ISO ones):

```
filter: 
{"where":{"and":[{"notificationOfNeedDate":{"gte":"2019-04-08T21:00:00.000Z"}}]},"order":["aCode DESC"],"limit":24,"skip":0}
```

I believe the solution is to migrate all YYYY-MM-DD to ISO dates

Is there a command to run in mongodb in order to "UPDATE" all YYYY-MM-DD to ISO dates (for that collection and field), respecting the locale timezone offset and the DST settings for that day?

Thanks

Comment: YYYY-MM-DD is actually a valid date.

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that the YYY-MM-DD does not have locale, so it considers it as ZULU time, while the rest are stored in Greek timezone, which makes the "start" of the day being stored as 3 hours earlier (T21:00:00.000Z). So when I search for a day the code is: {"acquisitionDate":"1996-06-05T21:00:00.000Z"}
Which fails to fetch the "1996-06-06" document, this is why I need to convert them to one format (all). Even when I search for {"acquisitionDate":"1996-06-06T00:00:00.000Z"}, I get no match for "1996-06-06".

Comment: Mongodb Dates do not retain TZ info, they are all converted to UTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another example why date values should **never** be stored as string, it's a design flaw. Store always proper `Date` objects, so you go in the right direction.

Your question is not really clear, string "YYYY-MM-DD" is also a valid format according to ISO 8601 (a date, just without time information).

You can use [$dateFromString](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/):

```
db.collection.updateMany(
   { timestamp: { $type: "string" } }, 
   [ {
   $set: {
      notificationOfNeedDate: {
         $dateFromString: {
            dateString: '$notificationOfNeedDate',
            timezone: 'Europe/Athens'
         }
      }
   }
   } ] 
)
```

You don't need to specify `format`, because ISO-8601 format is the default.

Then in your query you need to filter also on `Date` values:

```
db.collection.find({ notificationOfNeedDate: { $gte: ISODate("2019-04-08T21:00:00.000Z") } })
```

Of course, `ISODate("2019-04-09T00:00:00+03:00")` works also